# Ansible fail a playbook if directory not exist in windows

Tags: ansible

How can I fail a playbook if directory in windows not exist

```yaml
 - name: Obtain information about a folder
   win_stat:
     path: C:\temp
   register: file_info

 - debug:
     var: file_info
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`failed_when`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#controlling-what-defines-failure) on the task itself.

And then you can assess the existence of the folder based on [`stat.exists`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_stat_module.html#return-stat/exists).

```yaml
- name: Obtain information about a folder
  win_stat:
    path: C:\temp
  register: file_info
  failed_when: not file_info.stat.exists
```